# Is Ubuntu 14.04 available to use 4.7 kernel (or above)?

Tags: 14.04, boot, kernel

Is Ubuntu 14.04 available to use 4.7 kernel (or above)?

We tried that, but cannot boot successfully.
Reboot after install 4.7 kernel, it shows the following message and stick here:

```
/scripts/init-top/udev: line 14: can't create /sys/kernel/uevent-helper:
Permission denied.
Gave up waiting for root device. Common problems:
- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)
- Check root delay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Check root= (did the system wait for the right device?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules, ls /dev) ALERT!
/dev/disk/by-uuid/6f... does not exist. Dropping to a shell.
BusyBox v1.12.1 (Ubuntu 1:1.21.0-iubuntu1) built-in shell (ash) Enter 'help'
for a list a built-in commands (initramfs)...
```

Comment: Yes it is possible. 1. line 14 = `if [ -w /sys/kernel/uevent_helper ]; then
` 2. is the file present, can you create it? 3. did you check `/etc/fstab` for outdated options?

Comment: Hi I tried 4.4 kernel and It worked normally.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is about an unsupported kernel.

Comment: @Rinzwind same error with me today after installing 4.7.2 in Ubuntu 14.04. Looking at /etc/fstab appears fine plus can reboot with kernel 4.1.13 ok. The answer below for `CONFIG_UEVENT_HELPER=y` is confirmed by others on the net using different distros too. I'd like to find a short-cut to recompiling though.

Comment: FYI, ubuntu-16.10 aka yakkety comes with a kernel 4.8 that has the missing tag, and that is thus compatible with ubuntu-14.04

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Works for me.

Using `4.7.1-040701.201608160432` on `Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS` I got a similar boot problem:

[failure to mount root image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6dDGO.jpg)

Google yielded [this](http://tuxthink.blogspot.com/2014/10/can-not-create-syskernelueventhelper.html) so I confirmed the missing config:

```
$ cd /boot
$ grep CONFIG_UEVENT_HELPER config-4.7.1-040701-generic
# CONFIG_UEVENT_HELPER is not set
$
```

I edited my config to include:

```
CONFIG_UEVENT_HELPER=y
```

downloaded the kernel and recompiled.

Answer (score 1):

Kernel 4.7 is not supported in Ubuntu and never will be supported.

You install it at your own risk. As you noticed, something may not work.

Answer (score 0):

You can read this:

"**v4.7.2 mainline build**

These binary packages represent builds of the mainline or stable Linux kernel tree..."

At this link: http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.7.2/

Conical isn't obligated to provide us with kernel updates. But when they do they should make sure they are bug free, within reasonable limits.

Quoting the answer by @kenderland above:

"I edited my config to include:

```
CONFIG_UEVENT_HELPER=y
```

downloaded the kernel and recompiled."

These simple steps are all Conical needs to remove the bug they are publishing on their webpage. A google search reveals others have had to do this too.

Many people are reluctant to upgrade 14.04 to 16.04 at this time due to reported errors. Kernel 4.7.2 installs ok over kernel 4.4 which Ubuntu 16.04 ships with. Some people need the newer kernel version for newer hardware or driver fixes. People shouldn't be forced to upgrade to 16.04 in order to install kernel 4.7.2 nor should they be forced to recompile kernel 4.7.2 under kernel 14.04.

I hope Conical recompiles Linux Kernel 4.7.2 soon and updates their webpage with new links.

At the very least a warning could be on the page" "This Kernel Version is only compatible with Ubuntu 16.04 or 16.10".

FTR I'm happy with 16.04 improvements especially screen tearing but had to fiddle with Conky, PulseAudio and Suspend/Resume a bit.